# Delta Epsilon Proof Limit as $x\to -\infty$, equals infinity

Tags: calculus

Prove using the formal definition of limit that, limit as x goes to negative infinity of $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2+3\sin x =\infty$$

I know the definition is for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta<0$ such that $x<\delta \implies f(x)>\epsilon$

I start off by writing $$x^2 + 3\sin x > \epsilon$$
After I do some algebra I get, $$x>(3+\epsilon)^{1/2}$$ The 3 comes from the fact that $$1>\sin x>-1$$

I cant seem to find a relation that will let me have $$x<\delta$$ Please help me find a delta

Comment: Are you mean $x^2 + 3\text{sin} x \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: yes, goes to infinity

Comment: So, $x^2+3\text{sin} x = \infty$ is not appropriate.

Comment: I didn't know the latex characters for that arrow

Comment: use \rightarrow .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that $x\to-\infty$ than we have that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ $$x^2>\epsilon+3\\|x|>\sqrt{\epsilon+3}\\-x>\sqrt{\epsilon+3}\\x<-\sqrt{\epsilon+3}$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I never make that mistake when I'm doing computations but I guess my mind was somewhere else. So I can take delta = $$-(e+3)^{1/2}$$?

Comment: Yes you can take it.